# Maximum GPS-based location Sampling rate of smartphones

Tags: gps, android, mobile

I am working on Android application that needs to take GPS locations at the rate of 10Hz to 1Hz. I tried it by setting 100ms for time interval for requestLocationUpdates(_, 100, _, _) function. But GPS reading is changed after 10 consecutive reading which means the update is available every  second. Does it mean I can't get location update at higher frequency than 1Hz? The smartphone I am working is Samsung Galaxy A5(2017), Model SM-A520F. 
Similar questions are asked at the following links but I couldn't get exact answer.

1. [getting the highest GPS update rate from the GPS Hardware in my
   Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827142/getting-the-highest-gps-update-rate-from-the-gps-hardware-in-my-android)
2. [Nexus 5 gps update rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793100/nexus-5-gps-update-rate)
3. [What is the maximum sampling rate for GPS on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561300/what-is-the-maximum-sampling-rate-for-gps-on-android)
4. [GPS Refresh Rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461582/gps-refresh-rate)

Comment: It comes down to the gps chipset and the firmware of the smartphone 10Hz will be most beneficial, for reference http://www.furuno.com/en/gnss/technical/tec_rate

Comment: Thank you Mapperz. Though sampling rate depends on many factors, my quest is what is the maximum GPS sampling rate of current smartphones in an ideal environment? It looks it is 1Hz...If I get different answer i will post it

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Mi8 with the BCM47755 GNSS dual-frequency chip.  After building and testing a number of different Android function calls using the newest Android version (Pie), I have found the maximum refresh rate of the location fix to be 1Hz. The GNSS data collection also terminated at 1Hz.  No exceptions.