# Does GPS measure faster speed better or lower speed better?

Tags: gps, speed

Assuming the same signal condition (HDOP, SNR, or other environmental factors), does GPS measure faster speed better? or lower speed better? Note that the speed measurement here is derived from Doppler effect, not from the position difference.

I think GPS measures high speed better (showing low relative error) because Doppler shift is too slight to be detected in low speed. I found a comment in the Stackoverflow post (texnic's comment in the AlexWien's post) questioning the same thing but it seems that there's no clear answer.

I tried to find research papers about relation between speed vs measurement accuracy of GPS but couldn't find anything handling this topic directly. So, can anyone give me the answer about it?

P.S.
This question was also uploaded in the [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795904/does-gps-measure-faster-speed-better-or-lower-speed-better). Sorry if it violates the rule but I couldn't decided which one is the better place to post this question.

Edit: The "slower speed" means commonly < 10m/s

Comment: There is a limit https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276593/maximum-gps-based-location-sampling-rate-of-smartphones

Comment: AFAK The Doppler effect is measured using the accepted speed of light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light however that speed is different depending on density of the air, which makes rainbows and stars twinkle, temperature, humidity and altitude affect the density, along with the distance the signal passes through non-vacuum, affecting signals lower on the horizon more than overhead, this inaccuracy is very small but will be more significant in slower speeds. For a more definitive answer post on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ it's been over 30 years since my high school physics.

Comment: Strictly speaking, GPS doesn't measure speed at all. GPS measures *location*. Some other device uses multiple locations and a time interval to compute velocity. This question is is a form explicitly called out be off-topic by the [Don't Ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page, so I'm voting to close as *opinion-based*.